# News App RecyclerView Not showing fetched data from API

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have been trying to build this news app which is using a popular news API from newsapi.org. I have an issue and I'm kinda of stuck in between. The problem that I'm facing is that my App doesn't show any data fetched from API onto the recyclerView

In the same case if I try to show data by forming some dummy array the recyclerview works fine.

This is my MainActivity.java File

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewClickInterface{
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<NewsData> mNewsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    private JSONArray newsJsonArray;
    //private JSONObject mSingleJsonObject;
    private NewsAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView listOfItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);
        listOfItems.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();

        mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(this);
        fetchData();

        listOfItems.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    public void fetchData(){
        String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=240f35xxxxx12bb70xxxxxx";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            newsJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("article");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for(int i=0;i<newsJsonArray.length();i++){
                            try {
                                JSONObject mSingleJsonObject = newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                NewsData mSingleNewsData = new NewsData(
                                        mSingleJsonObject.getString("title"),
                                        mSingleJsonObject.getString("author"),
                                        mSingleJsonObject.getString("url"),
                                        mSingleJsonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                                );
                                mNewsArray.add(mSingleNewsData);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } //for loop
                        mAdapter.updateNews(mNewsArray);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int position) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, (CharSequence) data.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have hide the key in URL though the original URL works fine.

CustomAdapter :-

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder>{
    //private ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<NewsData> itemsData = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerViewClickInterface recyclerViewClickInterface;

    public NewsAdapter(RecyclerViewClickInterface recyclerViewClickInterface){
        this.recyclerViewClickInterface = recyclerViewClickInterface;
    }
    public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        public NewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    recyclerViewClickInterface.onItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewsData displayText = (NewsData) itemsData.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(displayText.getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.size();
        //return temp.size();
    }
    public void updateNews(ArrayList<NewsData> updatedNews){
        itemsData.clear();
        itemsData.addAll(updatedNews);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Other than I have NewsData.java file which is a basic data class
Secondly I have a RecyclerViewClickInterface which has only one onClicked abstract method, that doesn't forms a much significance in the given question.

Logcat

```
2020-11-09 01:09:57.206 13597-13645/com.example.newsapplication E/Volley: [2204] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=240xxxxxx61xxxxf0e8fbf
2020-11-09 01:09:57.932 13597-13645/com.example.newsapplication E/Volley: [2204] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=240xxxxxx61xxxxf0e8fbf
```

Please help me :)

[image: This is how App responds to given code]

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newsapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are getting an 403 error from your api, so you can't get any data and show in recyclerview. Your api key is invalid so you can't fetch data from api. One more thing, you  should hide your api key while publishing it somewhere.

Comment: Well the api key and the link is fine. I have rechecked it and also the link when opened in the browser works fine.

Comment: Please upload your Manifest file...

Comment: @piyushpk uploaded the Manifest file!

Comment: When I copy the link in logcat it gives an error on browser ?

Comment: @ErtuğrulUzun I have purposefully manipulated the link since it contains my API key.